# Lightweight alternative to Java's ResourceBundle?

Tags: java, resourcebundle

In some projects, I use the classical `ResourceBundle` mechanism to grab locale-dependent messages (exception messages, informational messages, whatever).

But I have a few problems with it:

- it is too "heavyweight" for my tastes; for instance, while I only need strings, a `ResourceBundle` can return an `Object`;
- handling of non existing keys is poor (unchecked exception instead of returning the key itself);
- you can stack bundles, however not in the way I'd like (adding a parent using `.setParent()` does not make the parent searched first, but the child).

I know code can be written to overcome the two latter points; however, if there is a library out there for handling messages in a more simple way, it would be even better! Do you know of one?

Comment: I am using NLS from Eclipse, It's very lightweight and I think it servers your purpose.

Comment: @PradeepSimha a quick Google search for Maven artifacts shows that it is part of artifacts providing OSGi capabilities... Is there a more lightweight version than the ones I've found so far?

Answer (score 4):

You could use GetText ([link](https://code.google.com/p/gettext-commons/)), take a look!

c10n is an interesting project too ([link](https://github.com/rodionmoiseev/c10n/wiki/Overview)).

Comment: Uh, it requires GNU gettext installed :/

Answer (score 1):

Well, answer to self...

I have continued to google around, tried and dug into Eclipse NLS and c10n as suggested, but the "simple" criterion I was looking for was not really there.

I have therefore started my own: [msg-simple](https://github.com/fge/msg-simple).